# Running one test on a remote test controller/agent

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have unit tests set up to run on a build server.  I just added a codedUI test which isn't running because I need to set the controller to run in interactive mode.  Because we couldn't alter the existing build controller, we set up a machine with its own controller/agent combo.

How can I, within visual studio, tell one of the tests (coded UI) to run under this controller/agent, while keeping the others as they are? I looked into testsettings files but it's not clear how I can get this done.

The controllers/agents are 2010, I'm on vs2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to configure your controller to run with Visual Studio. So, open the `Test Controller Configuration tool` and check that the `Register with Team Project Collection` option is not selected.

Then, from visual studio (2012):

- Right click on the solution and select `add new item`. Add a new `Test Setting` file.
- In the `Test Settings` window go on the `Roles` tab. Select `Remote Execution` and add the controller's (machine) name or ip in the `Controller` field.
- After you saved your settings, select `Test` --> `Test Settings` ---> `Select Test Settings File` and select your new settings.

Comment: I get "cannot communicate with the controller due to version mismatch" if I do this from VS2012.  Any tips?

Comment: Also - I'm trying to run just one of these tests on the remote controller, not all.  But one issue at a time, I suppose